# Correct way to implement foreach with NoRewindIterator

Tags: php, iterator, php-7.2

I have a `NoRewindIterator` that's passed to `foreach`:

```
$iterator = (new FileProcessor($this->input_file))->iterate($start, $limit);

foreach ($iterator as $line)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

With PHP 7.2, this gives a warning once it reaches the end of the collection, because `NoRewindIterator` does not implement `Countable`:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in [file.php] on line [line]

It makes sense that `NoRewindIterator` does not implement `Countable`, but I am not aware of a better way than `foreach` to traverse the collection with an iterator. What is the correct way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure this is the chunk of code that generates an error? As far as I know, `foreach` does not use `count` function. And it would be really strange if you cannot iterate `iterator` (i.e. `NoRewindIterator`):) I guess you use `count` somewhere in the code, and you cannot use it not only for `NoRewindIterator` but for any iterator. Use `iterator_count` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can use `while`:

```
while ($iterator->valid()) {
    $value = $iterator->current();

    $iterator->next();
}
```

Comment: This will work exactly like `foreach`. The only difference that it does not call `rewind` method on the iterator. Well with `NoRewindIterator` calling `rewind` method has no effect.